# How to populate TextFields with data from network calls in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I get User Profile information from a API call and want to populate the existing data (like name, gender etc) into my user profile field. However, I have no idea how to assign the state variables (`fullName`) of `TextField`s. 
The following code is a sub view of the full form view. I make the network call on the `parent` `view` `.onAppear{}`. 
Here is my Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormPartOneView: View {
    @State var fullName: String = ""

    @ObservedObject var userProfile = UserProfileViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                TextField("Full Name", text: self.$fullName)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .font(.system(size: 13))
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/1.2, height: 40)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(Color("Border2"), lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .onAppear {
                self.userProfile.fetchWithAF()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FormPartOneView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormPartOneView()
    }
}
```

This below code contains Full Name from decoded json data:

```
self.userProfile.userProfileModel?.payload[0].fullName ?? ""
```

So I would like to know how can I populate the Full name into the full name `TextField` in the form.

**Here is the form view:**

[image: User Profile Update Form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your model you can set it in `.onReceive` modifier, like

```
.onAppear {
    self.userProfile.fetchWithAF()
}
.onReceive(self.userProfile.$userProfileModel) { model in
    self.fullName = model?.payload[0].fullName ?? ""
}
```